Blender 4.1 Vertex Group Name Collision after Data Transfer
In Blender 4.1, doing a data transfer on a character's clothes to make it move with the character armature results in nname collision warning in the vertex groups.
The clothes move fine with the character, however this did not happen in 4.0.
Is there a fix for this?
